# Joining cells with Javascript

Tags: javascript, join, html-table, cells

I'm trying to do my best effort planning how to do this but I can't...

Example:

I have a table with id, but not td id's...

I have four td's en each tr.

```
<tr>
<td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td><td>ccc</td><td>ddd</td></tr>
```

So, what I want is to generate in the same table this output:

```
<tr>
<td>one two</td><td>three four</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>aaa bbb</td><td>ccc ddd</td></tr>
```

From 4 td to 2 td in the table showing the four values.

Comment: What have you already tried? Why don't you show us some code to starting on? It will be easier to help you

Comment: If you can describe the problem you are trying to solve doing there table changes, we could probably suggest an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I misread your target HTML and gave you something you weren't looking for.  Here's the corrected code that gives you the HTML result you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/DxVAS/6/

```
var t = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var i = t.rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var r = t.rows[i];
    r.cells[0].innerHTML += " " + r.removeChild(r.cells[1]).innerHTML;
    r.cells[1].innerHTML += " " + r.removeChild(r.cells[2]).innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have fun: http://jsfiddle.net/ungarida/4C29u/

Comment: Hi ungarida thanks for your reply! Only one problem... i wanna change the table automatically without push the button. Sorry but my newbie knowledge about jS is sooooo low.

Comment: Call the morphTable function directly.
$(document).ready(function(){
    morphTable();
});